# Groovy - how to read properties from a property file in a jar on the classpath

Tags: java, groovy, properties-file

Thought this would be easy and straightforward, especially in Groovy, but I could use come help with accessing properties from **property files that are in jar files on the classpath**.  I thought Java and therefore Groovy supported that as a foundational part of the language and runtime environment.

I thought I was getting close with this -

```
String propPath = this.class.getClassLoader().getResource("conf/Config.properties").getPath()

println "propPath = '$propPath'"

Properties appProps = new Properties()

appProps.load(new FileInputStream(propPath))
  
String appVersion = appProps.getProperty("version")

println "appVersion = $appVersion"
```

but propPath is getting set to the full pathname of the jar file (so far so good) but is is prepended with "file:" and it has an exclamation point followed by the resource name - `/app/lib/util.jar!conf/Config.properties` and so FileInputStream throws a FileNotFoundException (as expected).

Execution output:

```
propPath = 'file:/app/lib/util.jar!/conf/Config.properties'
Exception thrown

java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/app/lib/util.jar!/conf/Config.properties (No such file or directory)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a close look at the URL, which is the result from `getResource`
(URL is already the first warning sign).  It starts like a regular
`file://` URL but then has a `!...` in it - this the JVM telling you,
that the file you want is inside this archive.

`FileInputStream` only really can load files from the file-system, hence
the error.  At best `FileInputStream` could read the `.jar`-file for
you.

So you need a way read the content of your file from "the class-path"
and the shortest route is to request an `InputStream` from the
class-loader and pass that to load your properties:

```
Properties appProps = new Properties().tap{
    load(
            Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("conf/Config.properties")
    )
}
```

Comment: Aside, a warning: if you keep the `println`-debugging, be sure to _not_
print the input-stream if you plan to use it later.  Printing will
consume and close it.